# Помогите разобраться с Jtree java

Tags: java, исключения, jtree

Учил по книге Java 7 (4-е изд.) Авторы: Хабибуллин Ильдар  класс Jtree  там есть пример:

```
 Hashtable root = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable subtree1 = new Hashtable();
        root.put("Узел 1", subtree1);
        subtree1.put("лист 2a", new Integer(21));
        Hashtable subtree2 = new Hashtable();
        subtree1.put("Узел", subtree2);
        subtree2.put("Лист 3a",new Integer(31));
        subtree2.put("Лист 3b",new Integer(32));
        subtree2.put("Лист 3c",new Integer(33));
        subtree1.put("Лист 2b",new Integer(22));
        root.put("Лист 1",new Integer(1));

        JTree tr = new JTree(root);
```

при добавлении в переменную  `tr` типа `JTree` netbeans ругается и предлагает привести root к `TreeModel` или к `TreeNode` , после  того как я привел :

```
JTree tr = new JTree((TreeNode) root);
```

или

```
JTree tr = new JTree((TreeModel) root);
```

выходит такая ошибка

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.Hashtable cannot be cast to javax.swing.tree.TreeModel
    at layout.Layout.main(Layout.java:48)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Судя по использованию в коде примера давно устаревшего класса HashTable, да ещё и в качестве сырого типа, книге давно пора на помойку. Что там делает цифра 7 в названии мне совершенно непонятно, потому что так не принято писать уже со времён пятой версии Java, вышедшей ещё в 2005 году.

Comment: @user2865757 если вы посмотрите на документацию к классу JTree, то он в качестве аргумента конструктора использует именно Hashtable, а не HashMap. А еще может (тоже "устаревший") Vector принимать. Так что только по использованию коллекций из Java 1 нельзя судить о книге. 
Да и классы эти не устаревшие, их даже как Deprecated не пометили.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, вы импортировали не тот класс.
Класс javax.swing.JTree может принимать в качестве аргумента конструктора объект типа Hashtable.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#JTree(java.util.Hashtable)

А приведение к типу интерфейса TreeNode или TreeModel совершенно справедливо выбрасывает исключение, так как тип Hashtable не имплементирует данные интерфейсы.

Comment: Спасибо помогли ,  действительно  импортировал не тот класс, только учусь,  если можно посоветуйте   книгу по которой легче научится а то учусь уже несколько месяцев  ни как не могу освоить

Comment: Я бы посоветовал в первую очередь прочитать Хорстманна и Эккеля.
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/25151213/
http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/30425811/

Comment: Так же советую использовать не NetBeans, а IDEA. Хотя это личное дело каждого, но мне кажется, что Идея гораздо удобнее, понятнее и проще.